# how to use textbox value to search folder for pdf file and open pdf file

Tags: excel, vba, pdf, userform, openpdf

i want to use textbox1 value to search for the pdf file in a folder and open the pdf file.

```
    iso = Me.TempCombo.Value
    If Me.TempCombo.Value = "" Then
        Exit Sub
    End If
finalrow = Sheets("Hyperlink").Range("A6000").End(xlUp).Row

For i = 2 To finalrow
    If Sheets("Hyperlink").Cells(i, 1) = iso Then
        Me.TextBox26 = Cells(i, 1).Value & Worksheets("Hyperlink").Cells(i, 1).Value


        End If

    Next i

ActiveWorkbook.FollowHyperlink Address:="\\OPDD-2UA8302DBK\Users\rossa1\Desktop\Portal to Andrew Side\TORQUE MAPS\" ' & Me.TextBox26.Value"

End Sub
```

Comment: the value in textbox26 is from a hyperlinked cell on sheet "Hyperlink" when i click on the cell it opens the hyperlink in adobe. i like for textbox26 value to do the same. is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can open the a pdf file using:

```
Sub test()
    Filename = TextBox1.Text
    ActiveWorkbook.FollowHyperlink Filename
End Sub
```